# Classify all entire functions $f$ for which $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} \, f\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)=f\big(\frac{-1}{n}\big)=\frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is my solution to the problem in the title and below that are two questions regarding the given information.

Suppose $f=u+iv$ is entire and $$f\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg)=f\bigg(\frac{-1}{n}\bigg)=\frac{1}{n^2}\,\,\,\,\,(*)$$

Note that $z=0$ is a limit point of $\frac{1}{n}$ and $v(\frac{1}{n})=0$ for all $n$. So $v\equiv0$. Hence $f=u$. Since $f$ is holomorphic, it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0,\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{-\partial v}{\partial x}=0$$
So $u\equiv C$, where $C$ is a constant. By $(*)$, $C=0$.
 Hence the only entire function satisfying $(*)$ is $f\equiv0$.

1) Is the condition that $f(1/n)=f(-1/n)$ uncessesary?

2) What is the significance of '$2$' in $\frac{1}{n^2}$?

Comment: I'm always skeptical when I don't use at least one piece of given info.

Comment: Plus, your conclusion is false, because there are nonconstant entire functions that satisfy $(*)$, and $f\equiv 0$ does not.

Comment: (A word on terminology: You do not "prove" a problem.)

Comment: Surely $f(z)=z^2$ satisfies this as well.

Comment: As Eoin points out, $f_0(z) := z^2$ is a solution, so for any solution $f$, what can you say about the behavior of $f - f_0$? In particular, what can you say about its behavior at $0$?

Comment: In your last point, what is '2'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f = 0$ *doesn't* satisfy the given condition. You claimed that $v\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = 0$ for all $n$ implies that $v \equiv 0$. This is false (consider $f(z) = z$).

I think you are trying to use is the identity theorem: if $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic, and $\{z_n\}$ is a sequence with a limit point, and $f(z_n) = g(z_n)$ then $f = g$. Can you think of a holomorphic function $g$ which satisfies $g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{n^2}$?

Comment: With Eoin's comment, we know all such functions.